# Expected CEFR level after French In Action

Tags: french, cefr

[French In Action](https://www.learner.org/resources/series83.html) is probably the most famous course/resource for French produced in the last 30 years and is a beautiful example of a high quality, well-produced language learning course (very similar to the Spanish [Destinos](https://learner.org/series/destinos/)). It includes [video/audio](https://www.learner.org/resources/series83.html), [textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0300058217), [workbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0300176120), and [study guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0300058284).

Assuming a student learns everything there is to be learned in the course (all vocab, all sentences, all grammar principles, and is capable of understanding and reproducing everything taught in the course), what is the expected CEFR level after completing and absorbing every aspect of the course?